# Put Axis Range label above in am4charts

Tags: charts

I have a am4charts (v5) chart with a bars and a line (made with axis range), but i cannot put the axis range label above series line.

I tried with above param, with zIndex, but i cannot make it work.

I put the above param here in the axis range creation

```
let seriesRangeDataItem = yAxis.makeDataItem({ value: value, endValue: value, above: true});
```

This code reproduce the problem
https://codepen.io/javierflti/pen/wvxKRWo

As you can see, label "120" is not above bars

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `layer` property of the label will bring the label to the front:

```
range.get("label").setAll({
      ...
      layer: 1,
      ...
    });
```

[image]